# Google App Engine specific headers (like X-AppEngine-City) do not work properly for custom domains

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a google app engine instance running for a custom domain. When I hit the `*.appspot.com` url I get proper values for headers like `X-AppEngine-City`, `X-AppEngine-Region`, `X-AppEngine-CityLatLong` etc. But when I hit the custom domain url, I get only `?` in all the above mentioned headers.

I think since google doesn't send the UserAgent IP to the GAE instance, the instance is not able to determine proper values for the header. Any clue in fixing this issue will be very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you mapping your domain straight to the Google IP ranges/CNAME for AppEngine or do you have some sort of proxy such as CloudFlare infront of it.

If your domain name maps straight to AppEngine, I see no reason for those headers not to be set. (I think that around a year ago I used them on a custom domain myself to determine the rough user location in AppEngine.)

Comment: thanks for the clue. indeed there was a proxy which had got accidentally enabled